# ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost on ARM64 architecture

Tags: python-3.x, docker, arm64, catboost, catboostregressor

I am trying to build a multi-architecture image for ARM64 using buildx command. I am using python:3.8-slim as a base image and trying to install catboost using pip, but I am getting the following error.

**ERROR**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==1.0.4 (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost==1.0.4
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 python:3.8-slim

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    pip install -U pip && \
    pip install --upgrade setuptools

steps...
```

**Command**

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t dockerId:test-arm -f ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile .
```

**Alternatives I have tried**

1. In the Dockerfile I tried using the --platform=linux/amd64 which builds the arm64 successfully but still doesn't work when I deploy it on the ARM machine.
2. I have used anaconda for installing the packages but the error to install catboost remains the same.

```
#0 122.6 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
#0 122.6 
#0 122.6   - catboost
```

This is a shoutout to the #catboost team. I am currently working on a deadline and would like to know if the catboost has support for ARM64 over a docker image.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your first alternative.  `--platform=linux/amd64` will build the amd64(x86_64) version, not the arm64 version 
  
Have you tried another version on catboost?